# C++ : How to write a function to check whether a number entered by the user is in the array?

Tags: c++, function

The function should return the index of the element if the element is in the array or -1 if the element is not in the array.

```
int function(int a[], int length, int number)
{
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    { 
        if(a[i]==number)
            return i;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: The else-clause is worthless, causing premature jettison from your function as soon as the first non-match is encountered. Just put that `return -1;` as the last line of the function, outside the loop. Then consider that [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) already does this for you, and you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @WhozCraig ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

Comment: Thank you so much! I am I am a beginner and I have been struggling with this for a long time..

Answer (score 5):

You should erase your else block because it makes your program wrong

```
int function(int a[], int length, int number) {
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++) { 
        if(a[i]==number)
            return i;
    }
    return -1; 
}
```